# How can I run a query that returns the collation type of every table in our database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

We have some collation mismatches within our database and I'm trying to write a query that will bring back all fields' collation types like such:

```
SELECT col.name, col.collation_name
FROM sys.columns col WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Table1]')
```

only I need it to bring back every table.  I know there's an easy way but I'm struggling.

Comment: Why not just drop the `WHERE` clause that's limiting it to just `[dbo].[Table1]`'s columns?

Comment: Why not indeed ;).  Thank you, can you tell me how I can get the table name in there as well?  Haven't done DB stuff in a while, so kind of rusty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is limiting returned results to columns represented in `sys.columns` associated with `[dbo].[Table1]`. Remove the `WHERE` clause in your query to allow all other tables' columns to show in your result.

Additionally, you can join to `sys.objects` to get the names of the tables by their `object_id`:

```
SELECT col.name, col.collation_name, obj.name as 'table'
FROM sys.columns col
JOIN sys.objects obj ON col.object_id = obj.object_id
```